# Two forms in register page Drupal

Tags: users

I'm using [Profile2](https://www.drupal.org/project/profile2) and [Profile2 registration path](https://www.drupal.org/project/profile2_regpath) module and I created two profiles.

I want to display their registration form in `user/register` page. So two forms in one single page.

I set their path to `user/register` but these forms merged together. But what I want is two separate forms.

Like this:

[image]

Any suggestions?

Comment: Why you want 2 separate registration form on a same page.

Comment: I edited my question, check the img

Answer (score 3):

You can do it simple, add 2 form concurrent to the page you want ( if they are block  put two block in that page) and then with simple Jquery you can handle it with something like below code

```
(function($){
// change jquery selector with real ones
$('.user-register1,.user-profile-register').hide(); // or you can hide them with css
var selector= $('your radio option selecotr').value();
if(selector==1) {
     $('.user-register1).show();
     $('.user-profile-register').hide();
}
elseif(selector==2){
     $('.user-register1).hide();
     $('.user-profile-register').show();

}

})(jQuery);
```

**This code IS the way how can you achieve it and if you copy/paste it it will not worked till you changes its selector and values with your forms**